# How to do some changes at server side using SOAP UI

Tags: xml, web-services, soap, soapui

I am using SOAP UI to create a mock service.I have a folder which contains all my xmls.The SOAP UI works in such a way that what ever xml is put in the specified folder, will be available on the network. Then i can perform a GET service to get the contents of the xml.
Now i need to perform do some value changes in the xml.

Can i perform a POST request and changes the values of the xml?
If NO, then how can i achieve my goal?

Comment: Please add some more details on why you need to change the values of the xml and in what scenario, that will help me provide an answer. Will your mock service handle both GET and POST, will the system using the service use both?

Comment: Hi @Per I am working on a mobile application using phonegap. Actually Currently my mock service is handling GET request which will get me the xml values... Due to some business logic i needed to change the values in this xml so i though of performing a POST(which will change the server side data)... Can you suggest me on how to change the values of the xml?